# Is this the right way to initialize a variable

Tags: java, initialization

Is it bad practice to set `newWeight` to 0.0 (before the `switch` block) before I use it? If i just declare it, I get an error in the complier saying variable `newWeight` might not have been initialized.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SpaceBoxing {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your current weight ");
        float weight = s.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("I have information on the following planets");
        System.out.println("1. Venus  2. Mars   3. Jupiter");
        System.out.println("4. Saturn 5. Uranus 6. Neptune");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Which planet are you visiting");

        int planet = s.nextInt();
        double newWeight = 0.0;

        switch(planet){
            case 1:
                newWeight = weight*0.78;
                break;
            case 2:
                newWeight = weight*0.39;
                break;
            case 3:
                newWeight = weight*2.56;
                break;
            case 4:
                newWeight = weight*1.17;
                break;
            case 5:
                newWeight = weight*1.05;
                break;
            case 6:
                newWeight = weight*1.23;
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Your weight would be " + newWeight + " pounds on that planet");
    }
}
```

Comment: The original value is your _default_ value. Set it to whatever you want.

Comment: It's not bad practice as far as I know. If you're getting errors then I see no issue with setting a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate it before your switch but you should include a `default` case to the `switch` where you assign a value or perhaps throw an `exception`. The default case will be executed in the event that the previous cases do not cover the supplied argument.

```
int planet = s.nextInt();
double newWeight;

switch(planet){
    case 1:
        newWeight = weight*0.78;
        break;
    case 2:
        newWeight = weight*0.39;
        break;
    case 3:
        newWeight = weight*2.56;
        break;
    case 4:
        newWeight = weight*1.17;
        break;
    case 5:
        newWeight = weight*1.05;
        break;
    case 6:
        newWeight = weight*1.23;
        break;
    default:
        newWeight = 0.0;
        // or
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not bad practice. It doesn't make a difference.

You should, of course, test your code to make sure that it produces the expected outputs.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite good practise to initialize your variables, because when you will have there object and not initialize it you simply some times can get NullPointerException. So intializing variables(especially objects) might save you from that exception.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because your switch statement isn't guaranteed to set newWeight...if planet somehow was e.g. 7, then your System.out.println would be printing out newWeight without ever assigning it.

As some of the other answers indicate, you can either initialize newWeight to 0.0 when you declare it as you have done, or you can provide a default case to your switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

What would be better:

```
int planet = s.nextInt();
double newWeight;

switch(planet){
case 1:
   newWeight = weight*0.78;
   break;
case 2:
   newWeight = weight*0.39;
   break;
case 3:
  newWeight = weight*2.56;
  break;
case 4:
  newWeight = weight*1.17;
  break;
case 5:
  newWeight = weight*1.05;
  break;
case 6:
  newWeight = weight*1.23;
  break;
default:
  System.out.println("Unknown Planet");
  return;
}
```

Edit:  I posted this at the same time as someone posted the solution of throwing an exception.   I chose not to in my example because it may not be the intent for an unknown planet number to be an illegal argument.